How do I perform GitHub’s “Rebase and merge” in git with a single command?
Essentially, I want to merge a feature branch into main when the two branches have diverged and I can't fast-forward the merge.
If doing this manually, I would checkout the feature branch, rebase it onto main, switch back and merge the result. This, however, changes the feature branch, changes the working directory unnecessarily, and is just a little too much work for what is a straightforward option on GitHub.
What would be a good and safe way to do git rebase-and-merge without these drawbacks?

Since git v2.44, there is a new experimental command git replay that could help you  doing a rebase without conflicts without requiring a checkout (made especially for this purpose for git hosting services like github). See a previous answer on how to use it. You requirement is complex and will probably require to write a script...

@Philippe thanks. git replay is definitely interesting. However, it seems to be a rather lower level command meant for scripting, and it appears to not allow resolving conflicts. I found that I can instead use git cherry-pick in a similar fashion, with conflict resolution and even aborting. See my answer to this question.

To answer my own question, this simple command appears to cover most use cases:
git cherry-pick --ff HEAD..feature

Here, HEAD..feature will select commits that are in feature branch but not in the current one. The option --ff will ensure that, if possible, a fast-forward will be performed, as otherwise cherry-pick always creates a new, distinct commit.
The command will replay the sequence of commits on top of the current branch, stopping on conflicts. You can use --continue after resolving them, --skip commits and even --abort to cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.

For a single command, please try git rebase main feature_branch && git checkout main && git merge --ff-only feature_branch

git rebase main feature first checkout feature — exactly what the OP wants to avoid.

You can create a git alias:
git config --global alias.rebase-and-merge '!f() { git fetch origin && git checkout $1 && git rebase $2; }; f'


git fetch origin update local refs of remote repo
git checkout $1 checkout branch specified by the first argument
git rebase $2 Rebase with branch specified by the second argument

To use it:
git rebase-and-merge feature-branch main

If you want to force push to the remote repo:
git config --global alias.rebase-and-merge !f() { git fetch origin && git checkout $1 && git rebase $2 && git push --force; }; f

If you always want to do it to only the current branch:
git config --global alias.rebase-and-merge '!f() { git fetch origin && git rebase $1; }; f'

